# Firestore Security Rules: Can't check if document from sub-collection equals user UID

Tags: firebase, validation, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

## The problem

I'm currently implementing a system where users can vote on ideas created by other users using Firestore, stored in a root collection, where votes are stored in a subcollection of this idea.

Every user can only vote once on each idea and the system needs to be safe (you can't delete other person vote or create a vote as if you were another person)

How could I check if the user has already voted via security rules? It doesn't need to but I would prefer not using get() and instead use the document id as an identifier.

## What I have tried

Inside the Firestore Security Rules, I have made a simples verification for users to create valid ideas.

Then, I allow them to create vote documents inside (idea_likes) subcollection, I tried checking if the vote document wildcard matched the user id with no success, but managed to check if the field userid matched the auth.userid, though this makes harder a tad bit coding the client to show if the user has voted or not.

## How I have tried

Here is how I allow someone to create ideas:

```
     match /ideas/{document} {
       // Anyone signed in can create ideas 
       allow create: if isSignedIn()
       // Idea creation data validation
         && documentRequestNewData().idea is string
         && documentRequestNewData().title is string
         && documentRequestNewData().owner is string
         && documentRequestNewData().votes is number
         && documentRequestNewData().date is timestamp;
     }
```

And them right below this is how I've tried to allow someone to create votes:

```
match /ideas/{document}/idea_likes/{likeId} {
       allow create, delete: if isSignedIn()
         && request.resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid
         && request.auth.uid == likeId;
     }
```

I've also tried to split the {likeId} wildcard:

```
match /ideas/{document}/idea_likes/{likeId} {
       allow create, delete: if isSignedIn()
         && request.resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid
         && likeId.split('/')[2] == request.auth.uid;;
     }
```

Checking only for the document field works but doesn't help to prevent duplicate votes:

```
match /ideas/{document}/idea_likes/{likeId} {
       allow create: if isSignedIn()
         && request.resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;
     }
```

#### Any ideas?

I expected that if the user creates a vote document with an id equal to its userid I could prevent duplicate votes and make it easy to query this data in the front end.

However as shown using the wildcard and checking if it equals the request.auth.uid didn't work.

**Thanks in advance for any help**

Answer (score 1):

In security rules you can't check whether there is a document with a certain value in a collection, as that would mean the rules have to read all documents in a collection, which makes them prohibitively slow/expensive/non-scalable.

What you can do however is check whether a document with a certain ID exists. So if the documents are named after the UID of the voting, you can check if the user already voted.

To check whether a document already exists, use the `exists` function as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, there is a problem with the exists function, it registers a read and that does not guarantee that the document the user is creating has the same UID as his request.auth.uid, rendering the security function in this case, useless.

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen this is great information : "In security rules you can't check whether there is a document with a certain value in a collection"

Would you have a reference in the  google documentation mentioning it ?
Or is it an intuitive answer, based on the fact if Firestore security would browse/search in a collection to find a value, the database would be slowed down) ?